# Adding data into CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data

im new to CoreData therefore i am seeking a bit of help.

I have two entities named List(name: String) and Items(name: String, quantity: Int).They have a one-to-many relationship i.e. a List can have many Items. The logic behind them is that a user can create a new ListName with his name of preference and add items to it.

[image]

I currently have two table view controllers, one to add items to the Items entity and another one to show all the Lists entities as well as any Items which that list contains.

I have written the code for saving the items into an array of Items but my question is how can i write the code to implement the relationship so i can save the [Items] in their respectful List and also so when i load the number of total Lists in my tableView i can view them.

for example a List(name: Test) would have Items(name:sometext, quantity: 1), etc..

Comment: have you generate classes for this?

Comment: yes i have, i created the coredata entities and generated them

Comment: cool, do you know basic operations in coreData like: 1) Create Entity. 2)Save it

Comment: I recommend you create the inverse relationship, say "list", on `ItemsList` then you can simply set the item's list property to your `List` instance. CoreData will take of the link between the list and its items for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of issues which I believe you should fix, before we actually talk about solution to your question.

**Mistake 1 : Naming Convention**

Relation ships in core data should be named in such a way that, when they are placed in between the names of two entities they join, they make a meaning full sentence. It makes developers(in future whoever gonna maintain) life simple.

So rather than naming the relationship between list and listitems as listName, which does not make much sense, you should consider renaming as "Contains".

List -> Contains -> ListItems. Makes sense ???

[image]

**Mistake 2 :**

Creating relationship only one way from list to item and not creating a inverse relationship from items to list might sometime lead to unnecessary code in future,

for ex: Assume you are displaying the detail of item in perticular list and for some reason you wanna know to what list it belongs, if you dont have inverse relationship, you will have to query the core data to find to which list item belongs and fetch it later :)

Rather creating a inverse relationship will give you access to list object instantly.

[image]

Following the early mentioned convention, items -> belongsTo -> list :)

**Suggestion :**

Look carefully relationship contains is one to many where as belongsTo is one to one. That means a list can contain many items but item can only belong to one list :)

Modify it as per your need :)

**Lets answer the question :)**

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.managedObjectContext.performAndWait {
        let item1 = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Item", into: appDelegate.managedObjectContext) as! Item
        item1.name = "abcd"
        item1.quantity = 2

        let item2 = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Item", into: appDelegate.managedObjectContext) as! Item
        item2.name = "efgh"
        item2.quantity = 5

        let list = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "List", into: appDelegate.managedObjectContext) as! List
        list.name = "Test1"
        list.contains = NSSet(array: [item1,item2])

        //as an alternative you can save the list to item as well :) 
        //both will have same effect

        item1.belongsTo = list
        item2.belongsTo = list

        try! appDelegate.managedObjectContext.save()
    }
```

As you can see in above code,

I created item1 and item2 and because I dont have any list item I created list as well. In case you already have list fetch it from core data and use it :)

```
list.contains = NSSet(array: [item1,item2])
```

Statement above establishes the relationship between item1,item2 and list :)

**Be aware :** : contains is a set, so if you simply set it to new value, u will loose all the existing relationships, hence you should append new items to existing list.contains set :)

In my case list was fresh hence simply set it to new value :)

```
item1.belongsTo = list
item2.belongsTo = list
```

Where as above statements does the same job, here you dont have to worry about updating list's contains property, it will be updated automatically for you by core data :)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Worked like a charm thanks! How about fetching the List along with it's Items? I'm guessing it would be calling a different method than the usual fetchRequest?

Comment: You can make use of NSFetchedResultsController. There are plenty of tutorials on net, can't write it here as I'll end up writing up a whole blog then !!! You can always acess items from list object by saying list.contains and you can fetch all lists using NSFetchedResultsController and implementing its delegates :) Works like a charm with tableView :) Try reading a tutorial on it :) And please consider accepting the answer :)

Comment: The above comment does not mean that you can not use NSFetchRequest, NSFetchRequest returns data in the form of array and holding a large array in memory is very inefficient, where as NSFetchedResultsContrller works on the principle of PageFault :)

Comment: In addition to that NSFetchedResultsController also provides the delegates which provides you a capability to monitor the core data :) That means if you update your core data in some background thread you will get notified and your fetchedResultsController will update its data with background thread update :) So you have updated data always :)

Comment: i have used the NSFetchedResultsController to return the contains. It returns a NSSet with the data for that specific list. How would i convert the NSSet to something usable to show the data?

Comment: @pavlos : It returns the set of item. Each object in that set is item :) So access each item in set and show its details :)

Comment: @pavlos: You can also apply NSFetchedResults controller to fetch item also :) I just said you can access items from list instance as well :) does not mean you can't apply NSFecthedResultsController on item :) Anyway whatever the way u use contains will return set and NSFecthedResultsController will return array of items :) Access each item in set or array cast it as item (in fact if you declared NSFecthedResultsController properly u dint even need casting) and then access item property and show it in ur UI